# In PostGIS, does casting an `ST_Envelope` to a geography take the earth's curvature into account?

Tags: postgis

Using PostGIS, I have a table of data with geographic points defined as `last_known_coordinates` `GEOGRAPHY(POINT,4326)`. I want to find all of these within a geographic bounding box with given top left and bottom right geographic coordinates, and be sure that the calculations are geographic, not geometric, e.g. that the results account for the curvature of the earth.

The query I'm using is roughly:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE last_known_coordinates && ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326)::geography
```

As you can tell I'm a bit new to this, and I know what I want, but not necessarily how to do it correctly. Other answers hint that this is correct, but I'd like to know for sure: Does the `ST_Envelope` produced by `ST_MakeEnvelope`, when cast to a `geography`, take the curvature of the earth into account?

Comment: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3349/115

Comment: Seems like the android app doesn't pay attention to the url you paste in an picks the top "match" instead.

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks, that makes more sense.